# Eloquent relation with custom foreign - other key value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Is there a way to create an Eloquent relation function based on custom foreign - other key value?

For example I have level relation:

```
public function level(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Level::class, 'level_number', 'number');
}
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
public function nextLevel(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Level::class)->where('number', '=', $this->level_number + 1);
}
```

Is this possible or I have to write a raw query?

Comment: yes it is do you expect 1 or more results?

Comment: then add `return $this->hasOne(level::class);'  then in your controller via a closure on your relationship  `$var = Level::with('nextLevel,function($q){ $q->where('level_number', '=', $current_level_num+1); })->first();`

Comment: I dont want to extend the function outside from model since every time I need to call nextLevel the where statement u mentioned will be the same so I will be repeating the same code again and again.

Comment: so what happens when you run your current relationship?

Comment: It does not work. It's just an example of I want to do.

Comment: ok well run `return $this->hasOne(Level::class)->where('number', '=', $this->level_number + 1);` and see what returns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar situation, so I did some research in the Laravel base code and I found a very nice and clean solution.

Laravel (5.8) in [BelongsTo class](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/5.8/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.php#L99) uses something like this finally:

```
$this->query->where($table.'.'.$this->ownerKey, '=', $this->child->{$this->foreignKey});
```

`$this->child` is a variable which holds Eloquent object, so we can use the magic of Eloquent  [getters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor).

The solution is creating a getter with any name and using it as a second argument, as a foreign key in relations declaration:

```
public function level()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Level::class);
}

public function nextLevel()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Level::class, 'next_level_id');
}

public function getNextLevelIdAttribute()
{
    // any logic to get id (static value, db query etc..)
    return $this->id + 1;
}
```